# Package war of angular and spring boot application gradle

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rest, weblogic

I am working on a spring boot angular application. I have created a Get rest method on backend and for the front end I have use angular to show the result.

Here is the structure of the project.

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awqBU.jpg)

I have to package the application as a war (spring boot + angular). I have managed to create the war and deploy it on Weblogic server but only the REST Get method works, I can not display the front end.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
id 'java'
id 'war'
}

group = 'com.dannti'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

war {
  enabled=true
}

dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
}
}

test {
useJUnitPlatform()
 }

 def webappDir = "$projectDir/src/main/webapp"

processResources {
dependsOn "buildAngular"
}

task buildAngular(type:Exec) {
// installAngular should be run prior to this task
dependsOn "installAngular"
workingDir "$webappDir"
inputs.dir "$webappDir"
// Add task to the standard build group
group = BasePlugin.BUILD_GROUP
// ng doesn't exist as a file in windows -> ng.cmd
if (System.getProperty("os.name").toUpperCase().contains("WINDOWS")){
    commandLine "ng.cmd", "build"
  } else {
    commandLine "ng", "build"
  }
}

task installAngular(type:Exec) {
 workingDir "$webappDir"
inputs.dir "$webappDir"
group = BasePlugin.BUILD_GROUP
if (System.getProperty("os.name").toUpperCase().contains("WINDOWS")){
    commandLine "npm.cmd", "install"
} else {
    commandLine "npm", "install"
}
}
```

I think I should add something on build.gradle file but I do not know how to do it and I did not manage to find examples

EDIT:

I have added a modification in file by changing the directory where the result of angular build to "../resources/static"

```
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "../resources/static",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
```

But now I have an error that the js files of the angular application are not found.
Thank you.

Comment: Why packaging your app in a war, you can still package it in a jar and adding your angular contents in `resources/static` folder.

Comment: Could you please help how to modify the build.gradle file to copy the content in resources/static folder. I need a war to deploy it on Weblogic server.

Comment: I am not a gradle user but it should be trivial, you can find many examples on that topic.

Comment: I did find more examples using maven and not gradle. I have editing the question. Thank you